# Gson, enum and Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, json, gson

There is a json, contains `String` value for parameter, e.g. `status` and this json maps by `Gson` on POJO, and this parameter maps on custom enum.
JSON:

```
{"status":"on"}
```

POJO

```
public class StatusData {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Status status;
}
```

enum:

```
public enum Status {
   @SerializedName("on")ON,
   @SerializedName("off")OFF;
}
```

And if json contains correct values ("on" or "off") - all right, but if there is unsupported value e.g. "unknown" - then it crushes with `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference`. And question: is there way to change message of exception for understanding what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create new class of  **`enum`**

Use **http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/** to generate `pojo` class

Try this

```
public class StatusData
{
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna then work with enum, but no String, I know that I can change getters and setters and maps String and Enum there, but I just want throw exception with  understandable description

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StatusData {
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Status status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
}
```

Save your `response` as an object of `StatusData`

```
StatusData statusData=response;
String status=statusData.getStatus();
if(status.equals("on")){
  //code when status is "on"
} else if(status.equals("off")){
  //code when status is "off"
}
```

or use gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
StatusData statusData = gson.fromJson("json response",
                                        StatusData.class);
```

Comment: Yes, it will help to get around the problem, but I want just set custom message for exception, maybe some Strategies of Gson can help to solve this problem